# How to use InDesign SDK on Visual Studio 2013 for C++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, sdk, adobe-indesign

I have got a stuck on my research about “using [InDesign SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/indesign/sdk.html) to develop a plugin for [InDesign](http://www.adobe.com/products/indesign.html)”. Through my research, I have tried to start a sample project that shipped along with the SDK from Visual Studio 2013 (Note that all sample projects are using C++). Also, I have post many questions on InDesign’s forum to request a help but long time without response. I need your help to continue my research on this issue. The issue is described as below:

- Involved Document: plugin_sdk_CC2015_072_20150618.zip (An InDesign
  SDK – Downloaded from Adobe site -
  http://www.adobe.com/devnet/indesign/sdk.html)
- Development Framework: Visual Studio 2013 (C++)
- I have followed the guideline in folder
  “plugin\docs\html\index.html”.
- I open a sample project in folder “plugin\build\win\prj” on Visual
  Studio 2013.
- From the Visual Studio 2013 window, I click “Local Windows Debuggeer”
  to run the project. But after compiled the project, it generated an
  error message and the project cannot run further.

*Note: All document and sample projects are belong to InDesign SDK.*

I stuck there and cannot find a solution for this issue even I have followed the document from InDesing SDK strictly. Finally, the purpose of this research is to create a sample plugin for InDesign.

[image: Error message appeared when running project]

Regards

Comment: It look like Visual Studio 2013 doesn't know how to open .pln file after running the project. Some how I need to research on configuration VS2013 to make it be able to start the InDesign plugin project.

Comment: I got one more clue on this issue. That is the sdk.pln file is unable to start from Visual Studio. It is a plugin file of InDesign and it need to be run within InDesign only. The only problem is how can developers debug the project when they can't run the plugin file in Visual Studio!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my answer in detail:

The problem here is that Visual Studio cannot find the debug program for InDesign plugin. All we need to do to fix this is config the property of project and change command target of debugging to InDesign.exe which located under installed directory of InDesign.

[image: Config the project to locate the debug program]

Event you do the step above, you still not able to debug any project from Plugin SDK. Because, currently Adobe just provide a productive version of InDesign but doesn't provide debugging version for user to download. But the debugging version of InDesign is not free and need to be bought from Adobe site.

However, this is not the dead end to developers like us who just want to use free debugging version of InDesign to develop our own plugin. All we have to do is to build the project as release version. Then we can install release version of our plugin on productive version of InDesign and test its features.

This answer just show how to fix the issue from the question, for more detail everyone can contact me via email trind09@yahoo.com.

Regards,
Dung Tri